# How to make a more visually appealing bar plot with my data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot this dataframe using barh in matplotlib.

```
SAMPLE DF:

    genre              tracks_sold   percentage
0   Rock                  561        53.377735
1   Alternative & Punk    130        12.369172
2   Metal                 124        11.798287
3   R&B/Soul               53         5.042816
4   Blues                  36         3.425309

genre_sold_usa.plot.barh()
```

[image: PLOT]

I am trying to make this plot a little more informative visually.

I would like to have my plot this similar way but more visually appealing:

[image]

Please guide me with what else I can use to make it visually appealing.

Comment: This is kind of a subjective question. Maybe you can be done by switching the stylesheet? https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.11-settings-and-stylesheets.html#Stylesheets

Comment: The most appealing change I see is switching to only the % basis and eliminating the columns below a certain % so that it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `df` as the DataFrame, I just tried to reproduce your provided example. In my opinion, it makes more sense to rotate the `y`-labels. 'Visually appealing' is a subjective matter.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = df.plot.barh(y='tracks_sold', x='genre', color='mediumseagreen', ec='k', lw=1)
plt.xlim(0, 630)
plt.yticks(rotation=30)
plt.ylabel('')
plt.title('Top Selling Genres in the USA')
ax.legend_.remove()

# Way 1 of putting percentage values
for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.text(tracks_sold[i] + 5, 0.98*i, str(int(percentage[i])) + '%', color='black', fontweight='bold')

# Way 2 of putting percentage values
# for i, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
#    ax.annotate(str(int(percentage[i])) + '%', (p.get_width() * 1.02, i))
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more on how you placed percentage on top of the bars? Could you explain a little more on the for loop part of the code?

Comment: It is done using the `for` loop. You extract the patches (bars) and loop over them via `ax.patches`. Since you have 5 patches in the plot, the `i` will go from 0 to 4. `p.get_width()` gives you the height (horizontal) of each bar. You multiply that with 1.02 just to shift it slightly to the right. `str(int(percentage[i]))` just converts the percentage value to closest integer and then converts it to string. `ax.annotate` then just puts this string percentage value at (x,y) value where `x = p.get_width() * 1.02` and `y=0, 1, 2, 3, 4` which is the centre of each bar on y axis

Comment: Can I know what is ec and lw mean? I couldn't find anything in the documentation page. `ax = df.plot.barh(y='tracks_sold', x='genre', color='mediumseagreen', ec='k', lw=1)`

Comment: `ec` is short for `edgecolor` which assigns the edge color of the bars. You can see that it's currently thin black line. `lw` is short for `linewidth`. It controls the thickness of the egdes. Try changing it to `lw=3`. You can also put the complete word but `lw` and `ec` are abbreviations...both are accepted. `k` after `ec` means black color. You can also write `ec='black'`.

Comment: thank you. Just one more doubt the percentage is not placed correctly. I mean the placement of those percentage on top of the bars are not exactly in the middle like the image I placed above. Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: I added the second method in my answer code above and the modified output plot. It is now more or less in the middle. You can control the position further by changing the factor `0.98` currently. But it's a minor difference