# Creating alternative y axis labels for a horizontal bar plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a (clearer) repost of a question I just made, my deidentification was confusing people.

Hi, I'm new to graphing in python using matplotlib.pyplot and spent a good amount of time searching on this site and others, and trying to figure this out but I haven't succeeded in accomplishing what I'd like to do.

Using the code below, I have generated the following graph, which is a collection of courses and the percent of those enrolled who went on to complete the course:
What my code is creating:
[image]

However, what I would like to generate with python is something like the following (crudely made in MS paint to convey to you all what I would like my code to generate):

What I want to create:
[image]

The right hand side axis labels is the number of people who enrolled in each course, which is the additional information I would like featured. An alternative solution is to have the enrollment numbers featured within the graph, written on/at the end of the bars. But whatever works is fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = ['Physics','Chemistry','Economics','Philosophy','Computer Science','Sociology','Biology','History','Overall']
x = [0.0,33.333333333333336,50.0,50.0,50.0,54.54545454545455,58.333333333333336,100.0,51.851851851851855]
alternativeYlabels = ['54', '1', '3', '12', '12', '2', '11', '12', '1']
plt.barh(y,x)
plt.title('Percent Completion Rate of Each Course')

plt.show()
```

How can I alter my code to fit my needs? Also, how could I add vertical grid lines in my plot corresponding to each 20% in here as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are both the solutions: You need to add a `twinx` axis. Add the following lines before your `plt.show()`. If you want to put the values on top the bars instead of the second y-axis on right hand side, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991204/how-to-make-a-more-visually-appealing-bar-plot-with-my-data/51991950#51991950) similar answer which I provided few weeks ago (I attached the code below as well along with the output).

```
ax.xaxis.grid(True) # adding vertical grid lines
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Creating the right hand side y axis
ax_lim = ax.get_ylim()
ax2_lim = (ax_lim[0], ax_lim[1]) # Aligning the limits of both y axes
ax2.set_ylim(ax2_lim)
ax2.set_yticks(range(0, len(y)))
ax2.set_yticklabels(alternativeYlabels[::-1]) # Reverses the list
ax2.set_ylabel("# enrolled in each course",rotation = 270, labelpad=15)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Alternative desired output** (see the link in the answer) EDIT: vertical alignment of text based on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion

```
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.text(x[i]+1, i, alternativeYlabels[::-1][i], color='black', fontweight='bold', va="center")
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly (I just needed to add ax = plt.gca() as well)

Comment: Same here: You would use `i` itself as the vertical position. `ax.text(x[i]+1, i, ..., va="center"`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Edited and acknowledged your suggestion here too. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code from [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) matplotlib example which has two separate scales on both sides of the plot. The main difference is that here the second bar plot is a dummy one (each bar has a height of 0). I think this is the easiest way to do it (without manually adding ticks etc.)

```
# Initialize parameters as in your post
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = ['Physics','Chemistry','Economics','Philosophy','Computer Science','Sociology','Biology','History','Overall']
x = [0.0,33.333333333333336,50.0,50.0,50.0,54.54545454545455,58.333333333333336,100.0,51.851851851851855]
alternativeYlabels = ['54', '1', '3', '12', '12', '2', '11', '12', '1']

# This time draw the bar plot from an 'axes' object
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.barh(y,x)

# Draw a second 'dummy' barplot just to define the second ticks
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.barh(range(len(x)), [0]*len(x), tick_label=alternativeYlabels[::-1])  # don't forget to reverse the labels 

# Add the vertical grid
ax1.xaxis.grid(True)

# Add a title and show figure
plt.title('Percent Completion Rate of Each Course')
plt.show()
```

Running the code below should produce this figure:

[image: dual scales]

Comment: Although I already solved the problem using the other user's answer, I will still mention there is a problem with your graph FYI. Look at the right hand axis - there is only 6 ticks, unaligned with the nine total bars.

Comment: @zzzzz94 thanks for following up! I didn't notice that when posted the answer. The problem was that `plt.bar()` aggregates the values if you pass non-unique labels. I modified the code so that it works.

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried to do it myself. That's when I gave up and posted it here, haha.