# Matplotlib horizontal bar plot add values to bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the following code:

```
mixedgenres.sort_values(by = "rating").plot(kind = "barh", color = "steelblue", legend = False, grid = True) 
for i, v in enumerate(mixedgenres.rating):
    plt.text(v + 1, i - 0.25, str(round(v, 2)), color='steelblue')
```

I get the following chart:
[image]

How can I include values inside the graph frame and align to left so they are placed nicely under each other in a row ?

Here is the sample data to help figure out:

```
sampledata = {'genre': ["Drama", "Western", "Horror", "Family", "Music", "Comedy", "Crime", "War"], 
              'rating': [7, 7.6, 8, 8.1, 7.8, 6.9, 7.5, 7.7]}
test = pd.DataFrame(sampledata, index = sampledata["genre"])
test
```

Plot sample data

```
test.sort_values(by = "rating").plot(kind = "barh", color = "steelblue", legend = False, grid = True) 
for i, v in enumerate(test.rating):
    plt.text(v + 1, i - 0.25, str(round(v, 2)), color='steelblue')
```

And result

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991204/how-to-make-a-more-visually-appealing-bar-plot-with-my-data/51991950#51991950) answer of mine and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171321/creating-alternative-y-axis-labels-for-a-horizontal-bar-plot-with-matplotlib/52171704#52171704) as well. It is a duplicate.

Comment: This line  `test = pd.DataFrame(sampledata,  index= test.genre)` is incorrect and throwing error

Comment: 1) Sorry, I don't think that's a duplicate. Could not figure out from those.

Comment: 2) Sorry, sample data corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the complete working solution (skipping the imports). Two things:

1. You were using **unsorted** rating values for labeling and
2. You were adding too much of offset/shift horizontally.

EDIT: Vertical alignment of text as suggested by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

sampledata = {'genre': ["Drama", "Western", "Horror", "Family", "Music", "Comedy", "Crime", "War"], 
              'rating': [7, 7.6, 8, 8.1, 7.8, 6.9, 7.5, 7.7]}
test = pd.DataFrame(sampledata,  index=sampledata['genre'])
test.sort_values(by = "rating").plot(kind = "barh", color = "steelblue", legend = False, grid = True, ax = ax) 
plt.xlim(0, 8.9)

for i, v in enumerate(sorted(test.rating)):
    plt.text(v+0.2, i, str(round(v, 2)), color='steelblue', va="center")
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. Seems you didn't include part of your code. NameError: name 'ax' is not defined - can you please tell how to handle this? If I remove these two lines, than I just get empty picture with light blue values only.

Comment: Thanks! Works! :)

Comment: The vertical positions seem pretty arbitrarily defined. It should actually simply be `i` itself. `plt.text(v+0.2, i, str(round(v, 2)), color='steelblue', va="center")`